# Computer vision question (Image registration?)

Tags: computer-vision

Given two similar images, how can I determine the transformation required to 'convert' one to another? (as close as possible?) They will require rotation and scaling

Comment: This is a vast area of current research.  Google around for some basic tutorials, and from those you'll be able to get some articles for your particular field.

Comment: Aw nuts. Does it make any difference if I say that I'm working with 8-bit intensity images that are geometric shapes?

Comment: As it stands the question is very broad, and doesn't technically focus on a concrete problem you're having, as per the FAQ.  The user that answered has given you some resources, but again, it's a big field and a given problem has a lot of parameters.

Comment: @Vanny, we can help better if you give more details. What environment are you working with? OpenCV? Matlab?

Comment: MATLAB. I have two images of ellipses, one with known parameters (e.g. semimajor and semiminor axis), one without. I want to 'convert' one to another so I can calculate the new parameters.

Answer (score 4):

One common approach:

1. Extract image interest points + descriptors from both images. Use SIFT/SURF/GLOH/FAST/Harris, etc., whatever fits your accuracy/speed profile the best.
2. Match them (L2 norm, L1 norm, distance ratio test)
3. Use the putative matches to solve for a transform (rotation/scale/translation, affine, homography, etc.) with a robust outlier rejection mechanism like RANSAC, MLESAC, etc.

Here's a tutorial from Rich Szeliski (one of the big name computer vision researchers at MSR) http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70092